# How to add additional include directory on solution level?

Tags: directory, visual-c++, include

I have a big solution with ~30 projects(it's not my fault). I have several versions of boost. Each solution uses it's own version of boost. For now boost is set for each project(30 times). 
How to set boost on solution level? I want to say this solution uses boost_1.39, this solution uses boost_1.33.
I can add path globally on  VisualStudio level in `Tools/Options/Project and Solutions/VC++ Directories`. This way is bad, because then all my solutios use one boost. Or i can set boost on Project level. But how to do it for solution? Such feature is present on any build system.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Property Manager to put your common settings into a reusable property sheet file, which by convention has a .props file name extension. You can apply the sheet (or sheets) to your existing and new projects so that you don't have to manually set the common properties on each one. Any property defined by the included sheet will apply unless it's overwritten by the project's .vcxproj file / settings.

You can create a new shareable property sheet file in three steps:

1. Choose View, Property Manager. The Property Manager opens. By default it is in the left view.
2. Right-click the item/scope to which the property applies then choose Add New Project Property Sheet. Specify a name and location.
3. Open the new property sheet and then set the properties you want to include.

This is documented for all versions of Visual Studio from 2003 - 2015 under the subject [Working with Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[vsprops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e(VS.80).aspx) allows to set the same properties to different projects.

Comment: This is more fully documented under Working with Project Properties now.