# How to link a C++ project_A which includes other third party C libraries to another project_B

Tags: c#, c++, linker, include

I think this is a basic question, however I can not find any adequate posts about this topic or maybe I am just too stupid searching properly...

I have two projects in two different solutions. Project A is an application (.exe) using third party libs like ffmpeg (native C) and Project B is a DLL, which wants to use code of Project A (Purpose: A C# project is suppose to use funktionality of Project A via Project B).
From my point of view I just have to add include path to Project A in order to include source files of it and set the linker input to the Project B .obj.
However, when compiling Project B MSVS can not find the header file "libavutil/opt.h" of a ffmpeg Header:

```
#pragma once
extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
}

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libavutil/opt.h': No such file or directory.
```

Do I really have to set include paths to those ffmpeg libs?
If doing so I get many LNK2001, 2005 and 2019 errors. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: you have to tell it what directory to look for libavutil/opt.h in.  How you do that depends on what compiler you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way around setting up the include paths for your project. Possibly, you might facilitate this task, however, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038762/how-to-add-additional-include-directory-on-solution-level).

You might consider a complete redesign: If project B uses code from Project A, you might want to move all the code to project B and let project A use the DLL, too. If you find it easier making an EXE project a DLL than setting up the include path, you could switch the roles of A and B, renaming them and changing their types appropriately and moving the code *not* remaining in the DLL to Project B, using Project A as DLL.

Edit (in response to your comment):

- Project DLL:
  Receives all the code that will be shared between the C++ exe and the C# exe, including linkage to ffmpeg, etc.
- Project C++ EXE:
  Receives what yet remains of the former Project A. Will make use of Project DLL (more precisely: the DLL outputted from there) to get again whatever was previously incorporated directly.
- Project C# EXE:
  As you intended before. Of course, all the marshalling between managed and unmanaged code remains (you would have had to do this before anyway).

Comment: I have no problem with redesigning, as long as I can call a C++ function, which implements those ffmpeg libraries from a C# project. What structure would you recommend then?

Comment: @Richard I included a proposition in the response.