# Shared property sheet (Debug and Release) for a C++ visual studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a C++ visual studio 2017 solution having 50 projects added to the solution file.
I have few external libraries paths for both debug and release build separately.

Example:

```
    Debug paths:
     ./../External/adobe/debug
     ./../External/ms/debug

    Release paths:
     ./../External/adobe/release
     ./../External/ms/release
```

I do not want to add these paths to each and individual project. Is there a way to add these paths at solution level for both debug and release configurations.

I tried the Property sheet via property manager, but if I add a path in [.props](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) file, it is available in both the configurations. I want to have debug and release path separately in configuration.

Comment: How to do this quickly is not so intuitive, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081976/17034) shows how to use Shift+Click.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem add user marcos at the solution level.

1. You can add a custom property sheet file into every project configuration node in the **Property Manager** window by selecting all project at once like SoronelHaetir's answer, but it will add the custom property sheet file path to the project file (`.vcxproj`), which may not be what you expect to happen in some case.

   Overriding properties and targets in this way is equivalent to adding the following imports to all `.vcxproj` files in the solution

   ```
   <Import Project=="..\my_custom_property_sheet.props" />
   ```

   See also [Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings - To create a property sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170#to-create-a-property-sheet)
2. If you just want override project properties and targets from the MSBuild command prompt without changing the project file. you can refer to
   [How to: Modify C++ project properties and targets without changing the project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/modify-project-properties-without-changing-project-file?view=msvc-170)

   ```
   msbuild myproject.sln /p:ForceImportBeforeCppTargets="C:\sources\my_props.props"
   msbuild myproject.sln /p:ForceImportAfterCppTargets="C:\sources\my_target.targets"
   ```
3. It seems that we cannot add a custom **Property Sheet** to the at the solution level node in the **Property Manager** window, despite the following documentation:

   > In large solutions that will have many projects, **it can be useful to create a property sheet at the solution level**. When you add a project to the solution, use Property Manager to add that property sheet to the project. If required at the project level, you can add a new property sheet to set project-specific values.

   In effect, I found another reference: [Customize your build - Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets). May it would make sense to somebody who doesn't want to pollute the existing project `.vcxproj` files.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
     <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
       <BOOST_VERSION>boost_1_78_0</BOOST_VERSION>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup />
     <ItemDefinitionGroup />
     <ItemGroup>
       <BuildMacro Include="BOOST_VERSION">
         <Value>$(BOOST_VERSION)</Value>
       </BuildMacro>
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

Finally, to add a few external libraries paths for both debug and release build separately, maybe refer to [.vcxproj and .props file structure - Per-configuration PropertyGroup elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170#per-configuration-propertygroup-elements)

> There are multiple instances of this property group, one per configuration for all project configurations. Each property group must have one configuration condition attached.

For example,

```xml
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations"/>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

See also

- [.vcxproj and .props file structure - Property Sheet layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170#property-sheet-layout)
- [Set compiler and build properties - User-defined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170#user-defined-macros)
- [Per-solution property sheets?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b534d4dd-fd9e-413a-b978-ad52264d38e9/persolution-property-sheets?forum=msbuild)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to just select multiple projects in solution explorer and then bring up the properties window, you would then be editing all the selected projects at once.

If you create a property sheet file you would have to add it to every effected project configuration under property manager anyway which would very likely take longer (especially as I am not sure project manager is able to perform multiple selection while I know solution explorer can).